# Table row inside an anchor tag: Angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a table which has [routerLink] on each `<tr>`. But, since there is no  tag, I don't see the option "open link in a new tab" on right click. I tried surrounding the table row inside `<a>` tag but that just messes up all the CSS styles.

Is there a better/standard solution to tackle this issue?

This is what I tried:

```
<table>
  <tr [routerLink]="url">
    <a>
      <td></td>
    </a>
  </tr>
  .......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hyperlink inside the `<tr>` tag as follows,

```
<tr>
 <td>
   <a [routerLink]="url"> {{yourvalue}}
   </a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try `window.open()` on click of each row.